# N1QL queries vs multi key value queries in couch base

Tags: couchbase, sql++

We are using couch base node.js SDK
we are getting a list of ids from an external service (could be 200-500 ids) and we need to fetch documents from our bucket sorted, filtered and paged according to various attributes.

question is what is the best approach?
1 N1QL query , "SELECT x,y,z FROM docs WHERE docs.id IN [*list of ids dynamically set*] ORDER BY docs.title LIMIT 10 OFFSET 50"

or create multi KV queries and do the sorting ,filtering in the node app itself.

will the index give us any value when searching for a list of ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use USE KEYS with N1QL. You can also add a WHERE clause if you need additional conditions.

```
SELECT x,y,z
FROM docs
USE KEYS [list of ids dynamically set]
ORDER BY docs.title
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 50;
```

Comment: thanks! a quick follow up, when using USE KEYS, is there a point to define an index or the primary index is the most efficient?

Comment: USE KEYS does not use any index at all, not even a primary index.